# c++ string with extra 0x0?

Tags: c++

I have a strange with string with 0x0, can someone help me?

```
string a = funxx();  // funxx is a external func from Crypto++ libary
string b = "test"
```

if I print out the content of a and b, they both display as "test"

```
a.size() is: 5
b.size() is: 4
a.length() is: 5
b.length() is: 4

for( int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++ ) {
    cout << "0x" << hex << (0xFF & static_cast<byte>(a[i])) << " ";
}
print out: 0x74 0x65 0x73 0x74 0x0

for( int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++ ) {
    cout << "0x" << hex << (0xFF & static_cast<byte>(b[i])) << " ";
}
print out: 0x74 0x65 0x73 0x74
```

My question is, why `a.length()` and `a.size()` return `5` instead of `4`, and how to make `a` and `b` are equal?

Summary:
Thanks for lots of replies. I think the problem is clear for me now. The external `func` from Crypto++ libary return an extra null character in the string, and in string, the length is tracked separately. 
What I need to do is `std::string(a.c_str())`

Comment: `std::string` can contain embedded null characters just fine because the length is kept track of separately.

Comment: your print out is already very clear, `a` have an extra null character at end

Comment: Hi, Praetorian. I was not able to post the contents of funxx, actually it is a func from external library I am using.

Comment: Then you should add the documentation of what the function does, or is supposed to do, to the question. Clearly the problem is that the `std::string` object returned by the function contains a null character at the end.

Comment: Hi chris, the problem is a.compare(b) does not return 0, which means equal.

Comment: Hi Praetorian, sorry for that, I will do it next time. 
However, what is the best way I can do? Actually, funxx is a func from CryptoPP library

Comment: Why is that a problem? They're not equal, so `string::compare` is doing the right thing. Also, you can compare for equality using `a == b`.

Comment: @user3893836 You can edit your question, click the `edit` button underneath it. And use `@<username>` when replying, so people you address are notified of the response.

Comment: @Praetorian  the problem is I need use this string passing it to other external function as password. with a is OK, but b failed.

Comment: Please add these details, what you want to do, what `funxx()` does (if it's a function from CryptoPP, then use the real name instead of `funxx`) etc. to the question!

Comment: @BryanChen then, how shall I remove this extra null character at end?

Comment: `std::string(a.c_str())`

Comment: @BryanChen You should write that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to remove a trailing null from a `std::string`:

```
if (!str.empty() && *str.rbegin() == 0)
    str.resize(str.size() - 1);
```

Comment: or use `back()` and `pop_back()`

Comment: @Potatoswatter I thought of that, but tried to avoid C++11-only features.